# HighCharts Tooltips display over the bar, preventing drilldown

Tags: css, highcharts

I have a highcharts bar chart. I have things working like I want, but the issue is that the tooltips display over the bar that is being hovered. Normally this would be the wanted functionality. But I have drill downs and I need the tooltip to be just a bit above the bar that is being hovered.

Please do not suggest a fixed position tooltip I would like an onHover tooltip.

**Issue:** Tooltips display over the bar that is being hovered.

**Desired Output:** ToolTip displays just above the hovered bar.

**Here is a picture:** (the arrow is where the mouse was when the picture was taken.) [image]

**Here is the desired output:**(notice how the tooltip is above the mouse.) [image]

**Current Tooltip Code:**

```
     $('#ChartContainer2').highcharts({

        //other options....

               tooltip: {
                useHTML: true,
                shared: true,
                headerFormat: '<small>{point.key}</small><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color: {series.color}">{series.name}: </td>' +
                    '<td style="text-align: right"><b>{point.y}%</b></td></tr>',
                footerFormat: '</table>',

                },
```

**Here is the options in my Theme code:**

```
            //other options....

            tooltip: {

                borderWidth: 0,
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(211, 211, 211)',
                shadow: false
            },
```

Comment: If built-in tooltip positioner doesn't work for you, then you have an option to write your own, see more about [`tooltip.positioner`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.positioner).

Comment: All I want to do is offset the tooltip up like 30px, I have to write my own just to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure where is the problem. You have point position, so just return modified value, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/oo094od7/ Or if you don't want to use `positioner`, then set `tooltip.distance`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/ybyz4uz9/ (distance option is less flexible, though). Anyway, in my optinion, I would change tooltip format, to make it smaller.